# Pandas Performance comparison apply vs map

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm comparing the performance of calculating a simple multiplication of a Dataframe column using both `map` and `apply`

I expected the `apply` version to be much, much faster because I'm doing a vectorized numpy function instead of operating on an element at a time.

However, it was not the case, both version had equal performance:

apply version:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': np.random.random(size=10000000)
})

df1['2x'] = df1['x'].apply(lambda arr: arr*2)
# CPU times: user 1.64 s, sys: 180 ms, total: 1.82 s
# Wall time: 1.82 s
```

map version:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': np.random.random(size=10000000)
})

df2['2x'] = df2['x'].map(lambda element: element *2)
# CPU times: user 1.65 s, sys: 180 ms, total: 1.83 s
# Wall time: 1.83 s
```

Versions used: Python 3.6.7, Pandas 0.24.2, Numpy 1.16.3

**Why isn't the `apply` version much faster than the `map` version, since it's using numpy vectorized functions?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`apply()` is just a for-loop in disguise, it is not vectorized  You've fooled yourself by calling the lambda element `arr`, but actually it is a scalar.

Instead, keep it simple, this is like 100x faster:

```
df1['2x'] = df1['x'] * 2
```

Comment: i see, so there is no advantage to using `apply` vs `map`?

Comment: @FelipeAlmeida both `.apply` and `.map` are simply python for-loops in disguise, they are convenience methods not meant for performance.

Comment: But if I use two square brackets instead of one (returning a dataframe instead of a series), apply is indeed much faster than map on a column, look: [notebook](https://github.com/queirozfcom/python-sandbox/blob/master/python3/notebooks/pandas-large-data/main.ipynb)

Comment: @FelipeAlmeida: That's because now you're applying one function call per column instead of one per row.  So the [[]] apply is the same as my simpler solution in my answer.